# How to add a delay for splash screen in electron

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, electron

I want the splash screen to stay on the screen for 3 seconds but electron loads the application way faster than that and so it stays on for barely a split second.

I'm using Angular to make the SPA.

This is the electron function for the splashscreen and the main window

```js
app.on("ready", () => {
  // create main browser window
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    titleBarStyle: "hidden",
    width: 1920,
    height: 1080,
    show: false, // don't show the main window
  });
  // create a new `splash`-Window
  splash = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 450,
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
  });
  splash.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/splash.html`);
  mainWindow.loadURL(`file://${__dirname}/dist/MedalFrontEnd/index.html`);

  // if main window is ready to show, then destroy the splash window and show up the main window
  function showFunc() {
    mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
      splash.destroy();
      mainWindow.show();
    });
  }

  showFunc();
});
```

Comment: I'm not really an electron guy, but couldn't you just do setTimeout(() => {splash.destroy(); mainWindow.show();}, 3000) ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `setTimeout` in your function to wait for 3 seconds. Something like below should work -

```
function showFunc() {
    mainWindow.once("ready-to-show", () => {
        setTimeout(function(){      
            splash.destroy();
            mainWindow.show();
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```